# Custom form fields in Drupal 8

Tags: forms, drupal-8, calculated-field

I am new to Drupal. I have a working webapp in PHP/MySQL which I am trying to port to Drupal. Here is my problem:

I have a table called Patients with a DoB (Date of Birth) field. In the webapp, the input form takes in information as "Age" in years and months, and inputs an approximate DoB by subtracting from current date (This is because most of the patients, where this is used, are not aware of their DoB).

How to do this in Drupal? Till now, I have setup a content type called Patients with a field called DoB. It works fine with a proper calendar drop-down etc. Then I am stuck. How to achieve the above-mentioned functionality? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your "table" saved in drupal as a custom entity? Does the data need to be saved in the database as the calculated value? Or do you save the input values and just need to display the calculated value, if you just need to display it as calculated, you could probably just use a [custom field formatter](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-field-types-widgets-and-formatters/create-a-custom-0)

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you need is very custom, by default Drupal cannot suggest something like this. The best way to receive the field with exactly the same functionality - it's to develop such field type from scratch. Please check the official documentation.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-field-types-widgets-and-formatters/create-a-custom